# Failed error when installing service?

Tags: windows, windows-services

Im trying to install a service on my host.
and i keep getting this error:

```
"failed installing 'stphost' service"
```

It doesnt give me any other error or information, so Im  not sure where I can debug this, being new to this?

Where can I check what is going on wrong?

here is part of the new service.bat

```
    set CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME%
    set EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat7.exe
    set SERVICE_NAME=STPHOST
    set PR_DISPLAYNAME=STP Web Host 4.1

set PR_DESCRIPTION=Spectrum Technical Publications web hosting service.
set PR_INSTALL=%EXECUTABLE%
set PR_LOGPATH=%CATALINA_BASE%\logs
set PR_CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;

rem Set the server jvm from JAVA_HOME
set PR_JVM=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
if exist "%PR_JVM%" goto foundJvm
rem Set the client jvm from JAVA_HOME
set PR_JVM=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
if exist "%PR_JVM%" goto foundJvm
set PR_JVM=auto

:foundJvm
echo Using JVM:              %PR_JVM%
"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --Startup auto --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams start --StopParams stop

if not errorlevel 1 goto installed

echo Failed installing '%SERVICE_NAME%' service
```

The old service i that is working right now its:

```
set CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME% 
    set EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat5.exe  
    set SERVICE_NAME=STPHOST    
    set PR_DISPLAYNAME=STP Web Host 3.0
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs? The event viewer?

Comment: Are you running as Admin?

Comment: yes im running as admin, and i can only see tomcat.text log and doesnt really tell me anything

Comment: i just notice that i have another service that has the same name that im trying to run, could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you already have that service installed then?

Comment: i do have one that is old uses tomcat 5.3 and the new one im trying to install has 7.0

Comment: Check the Windows Event Log to see what errors are there. "tomcat.text" is not the place where service installation errors would be logged.

Comment: this is error i get "The STPHOST2 service terminated with service-specific error 4 (0x4)."

Answer (score 0):

i solve the issue by removing the old host in the service and adding the new one, since you cant have two with the same name , and i restated everything